# ¿Cómo tomo la fecha del día miércoles de una semana y la fecha del día miércoles de la siguiente semana?

Tags: php, mysql, array, datetime

espero que esten muy bien, eh bueno, mi pregunta, aun no tiene codigo, por eso no lo publico, sin embargo me gustaria que me dieran una idea de como hacer, para obtener estas fechas (dia miercoles de la semana actual, y miercoles de la semana siguiente), estas fechas las quiero para hacer un COUNT de registros entre esas fechas.

Comment: Una opción sería usar, en conjunto, las funciones [DATE_ADD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) y [WEEKDAY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday).

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo resolví.